# change some value in array javascript before post to API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays

I have an array :

```
[{"IDAlokasiEmiten":154,"IDOrganization":12,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ANTM","NameEmiten":"AAneka Tambang (Persero) Tbk"},{"IDAlokasiEmiten":0,"IDOrganization":null,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ADHI","NameEmiten":"Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk"}]
```

How do I change some values before I post to API?

I want POST to API into:

```
[{"IDAlokasiEmiten":0,"IDOrganization":12,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ANTM","NameEmiten":"AAneka Tambang (Persero) Tbk"},{"IDAlokasiEmiten":0,"IDOrganization":12,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ADHI","NameEmiten":"Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk"}]
```

Here is my AngularJS:

```
// GET Detail Alokasi Emiten
    $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten = [];
    $scope.addItemAlokasi = function () {
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.push({
            IDAlokasiEmiten: 0,
            IDOrganization: 12,
            NamaOrganization: '',
            CodeEmiten: $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.CodeEmiten,
            NameEmiten: $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NameEmiten
        });
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.IDAlokasiEmiten = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.IDOrganization = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NamaOrganization = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.CodeEmiten = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NameEmiten = ''
    };
    $scope.resetForm = function () {
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.IDAlokasiEmiten = ''; 
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.IDOrganization = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NamaOrganization = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.CodeEmiten = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NameEmiten = ''
    };
    $scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.splice(index, 1);
    };
    $scope.getTotalItems = function () {
        return $scope.detailDaftarEmiten.length;
    };
```

But it doesn't work :(

I want to set all value array for (`IDAlokasiEmiten=0` and `IDOrganization=12`).

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj=your code;
obj[0]["IDOrganisation"]=12;
//0 -> first object in array
```

This is simple javascript. You should visit MDN and learn a bit more of it...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this using plain javascript without library using `forEach` method.

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
arr=[{"IDAlokasiEmiten":154,"IDOrganization":12,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ANTM","NameEmiten":"AAneka Tambang (Persero) Tbk"},{"IDAlokasiEmiten":0,"IDOrganization":null,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ADHI","NameEmiten":"Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk"}]
arr.forEach(function(a){
  a["IDAlokasiEmiten"]=0;
  a["IDOrganization"]=12;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following statements.

```
var arr = [{"IDAlokasiEmiten":154,"IDOrganization":12,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ANTM","NameEmiten":"AAneka Tambang (Persero) Tbk"},{"IDAlokasiEmiten":0,"IDOrganization":null,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ADHI","NameEmiten":"Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk"}];
arr.map(i=>{i.IDAlokasiEmiten=0;i.IDOrganization=12;})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [{"IDAlokasiEmiten":154,"IDOrganization":12,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ANTM","NameEmiten":"AAneka Tambang (Persero) Tbk"},{"IDAlokasiEmiten":0,"IDOrganization":null,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ADHI","NameEmiten":"Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk"}];

a.forEach(function(e) {
  e.IDAlokasiEmiten = 0;
  e.IDOrganization = 12;
});

JSON.stringify(a);
```

Comment: This might answer the question, but it's probably a good idea to provide some explanation as to why and how this works. Code-only answers aren't so helpful to others who find this in future.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, its json data.

You have to first deserialize and then serialize back to json.

```
public class Sample
{
    public int IDAlokasiEmiten { get; set; }
    public int? IDOrganization { get; set; }
    public object NamaOrganization { get; set; }
    public string CodeEmiten { get; set; }
    public string NameEmiten { get; set; }
}
```

Use NewtonSoft.Json dll for the same.

You can deserialize this json to `SampleClass[]` and then iterate through it and set property of each object.

**json**

```
[{
    "IDAlokasiEmiten": 154,
    "IDOrganization": 12,
    "NamaOrganization": null,
    "CodeEmiten": "ANTM",
    "NameEmiten": "AAneka Tambang (Persero) Tbk"
}, {
    "IDAlokasiEmiten": 0,
    "IDOrganization": null,
    "NamaOrganization": null,
    "CodeEmiten": "ADHI",
    "NameEmiten": "Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk"
}]
```

**C# Code:**

```
    string json = ""; //your json string.
    SampleClass[] arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClass[]>(json);
    foreach (SampleClass obj in arr)
    {
        obj.IDAlokasiEmiten = 0;
        obj.IDOrganization = 12;
    }
```